# SP 2019 CSOM Console App

Tags: csom, credentials

I am trying to develop a CSOM console app for a SharePoint 2019 site and I'm having trouble authenticating.

I've tried:

```
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

and

```
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
context.Credentials = credentials;
```

(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials had empty strings for Domain, Password, and UserName)

I've also tried

```
var credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);
```

after having created the secure password.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've used both `NetworkCredential` and `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` successfully in many programs in the past. Are you on the same network as the SharePoint server(s)? Not being on the same network is the only thing I can think of that may cause problems.

Comment: I'm on  a virtual desktop in the same domain as the server, I can connect with the server using PnP Powershell

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include SharePoint client DLL before, for example:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
```

Or with a direct path:

```
Add-Type -Path "E:\Apps\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "E:\Apps\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

And then you can try :

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Login, $Password, $Domain)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials
```

I tested it with SharePoint 2019.

```
$rootWebsite = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($rootWebsite) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: This looks like PowerShell which I might have to consider using. I am changing permissions on list items which is why I decided to use a console application instead

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't answer with C# code but the syntax is almost the same! Maybe you could try in PowerShell to check if the error is the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've used PnP PowerShell and it was a piece of cake.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "<site url>" -CurrentCredential    

$list = "account"
$startId = 0
$endId = 5000

for($i = $startId; $i -le $endId; $i++){

    $item = Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Id $i

    if($item["DocumentType"] -eq "Protection"){    
        if(-not(Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $item -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments")){    
            Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $list -Identity $i -AddRole "Full Control" -Group "CRM Owners" -ClearExisting
            Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $list -Identity $i -AddRole "Contribute" -Group "CRM Protection Members"
        }
    }
}
```

I think some network setting was blocking the communication protocol my console app was using